# Firebug pale colors in HTML tab - how to show them

Tags: html, css, firebug, firebug-lite

How could I somehow show styles for invisible tags showed in Firebug? I have no idea why they are pale/invisible and I need to find out why.

[image: firebug HTML tab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug pales out those elements that are invisible or hidden from view in the browser. According to your example shown here. There are 2 types of HTML elements that are invisible / pale.

1. `<input type="hidden" />` is as the name suggests hidden type and is never shown on the page but can contain some important data for other functionality of the web page.
2. There is a `<div>` element which does not contain any content, nor it has its height or width defined. So what do you expect to show for that div?

---

### EDIT:

If you want them to be shown on your webpage then:

For `<input type="hidden" />` you can copy its `value` to some other elements to show what it contains. You can do this using javascript or jQuery.

For the `<div>` element. Either add some content to it like:

```
<div class="ui-icon">
    Your content
</div>
```

or specify its size (i.e. height and width) also display it as block with some border.

```
<div class="ui-icon" style="hieght:10px; 
       width:100px; display: block; border: 1px solid red"> 
</div>
```